# extracting foreground refined (in actual form) from a video using OpenCv C++ using absdiff

Tags: c++, opencv, foreground

This function takes an input video stream and process it:
It takes 100 frames and calculates an average and makes it background, and then subtracts the current image from the background model and extracts  the foreground but its very noisy, can anyone kindly tell me how to display the foreground objects in its actual form.

```
int foregroundNbackground(VideoCapture cap){

    int count=0;
    vector<Mat> img_bg;
    Mat img, img_diff, b1;
    Mat Background = T12(cap);    // This calculates the average of previous 100 frames and make it the background model
    imshow("Model", Background);
    while(1){
        cap >> img;
        if(count < 100){
            img_bg.push_back(img);
        }
        if(count == 100){
            Background =  getMean(img_bg);
            cvtColor(Background, b1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            imshow("Model", b1);
            count = 0;
            img_bg.clear();
        }
        absdiff(img, Background, img_diff);
        count++;
        cvtColor(img_diff,img_diff, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(img_diff,img_diff,80,255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        imshow("Task13", img_diff);
        waitKey(33);
    }
}
```

Comment: getMean is the function which is called inside T12 to calculate the mean of the vector of images and return a mean Mat.

Comment: Once you've saturated `img_diff`, use it as a mask to extract the foreground from the original frame `img`.

Comment: 2 things that you can try - 1) increase the number of frames that you're using to compute the avg background. 2) increase the threshold value in the `threshold` function from 80